# Restricting universal quantifiers with conditions?

Tags: notation, quantifiers

I want to express *"For every $x\in\mathbb R$ that has (at least) one $p\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb N$, such that $x=\frac pq$, $x\in\mathbb Q$ is true"* with logical quantifiers, just like this
$$\bigwedge_{x\in\mathbb R}x\in\mathbb Q~~~\text{(condition missing)}~.$$
But where to put the condition *"that has one $p\in\mathbb Z$..."* ?
$$\bigwedge_{x\in\mathbb R}\bigvee_{\matrix{p\in\mathbb Z\\q\in\mathbb N}}x=\frac pq$$
would be wrong, because not every real number can be written as a quotient of integers, so my question: Is there a notation allowing me to restrict universal quantifiers with a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative clause translates to a condition. *If* there exist such and such $p,q$ *then* $ x$ is rational. So the full formula has the general form "for all $x$ ((there exist $p,q$ such that etc) -> $x$ so and so)"

Comment: $\bigwedge_{x\in\mathbb R}\left(\left(\bigvee_{\matrix{p\in\mathbb Z\\q\in\mathbb N}}x=\frac pq\right)\rightarrow x\in\mathbb Q\right)$ would be right?

Comment: Yes, if we agree that the existential quantifier has precedence over the arrow (I can never remember this so I added an extra pair of brackets). Sorry about the verbal notation, I am currently on a TeX-hostile phone :-)